# Renaming column names with a matching row value from another dataset in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv, merge

I am using Pandas. I have a DataFrame df_1 with columns

`['1', '3', '5', '10']`.

I have another DataFrame df_2 as below:

Code | Species

1    |   A

2   | B

3  |  C

4  |  D

5  |  E

.....keeps going

How do I use dataframe2 to change the column names in dataframe1 to the species values

['A', 'C', 'E', 'etc']

based on the matching code value?

Basically, I have animal species that have coded numbers assigned to them and I am trying to get the species names to replace the coded numbers that are the current column values. Some of the coded values will not be matched as there is a longer list of species than needed.

I have tried the code below with no luck. Maybe it is oudated.

`df_1.rename(columns=df_2.set_index('Code')['Species'], inplace= True)`

Comment: You could try: ``df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int).map(df2.set_index("Code").Species)``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks. I get this when I try that TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype int64. And if I remove the .astype(int) then it does change all the column names, but it changes them to NaN values?

Comment: could you run it independently and see? try `df1.columns.astype(int)` and see if you get the same error. your columns should be strings, hence the conversion to integers, to match with what is in `df2`. I am assuming you tested it on the sample data you shared

Comment: @sammywemmy I get the same error. And just to clarify, the code column is its own column, it's not the index.

Comment: strange. your column is a string dtype, so it should be able to change to int. I assume they are all numbers ('1', '5', '10', ...) or are there letters embedded in the columns?

Comment: @sammywemmy there is only numbers in the rows. When I run ```df_1.columns.dtype```, I get back  dtype('O')

Comment: not sure why it fails, could you try : ``mapping = dict(zip(df2.Code.astype(str), df2.Species))``, then ``df1.rename(columns=lambda x: mapping.get(x, ""))``

Comment: @sammywemmy I figured out a work around. I changed them all to strings instead.... ```df_2['Code'] = df_2['Code'].astype(str)``` Thanks for the assist!

Comment: whew! glad it worked out